# How to spread the values from a column in Hive?

Tags: hive

One field of table is made up of many values seperated by comma,
for example, a record of this field is:

> 598423,4803510,599121,98181856,1666529,106317962,4061964,7828860,598752,728067,599809,8799578,1666528,3253720,601990,601235

I want to spread the values in every record of this field in Hive.
Which function or method I can use to realize this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "spread". 
If you want an output table that has a value in every row like:

```
598423
4803510
599121
```

Then you could use `explode(split(data,',')`

Otherwise, if each input row has exactly 16 numbers and you want each of the numbers to reside in a different column, you have two options:

1. Define the comma as a delimiter for the input table `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`
2. Split a single column into 16 columns using the split UDF: `SELECT split(data,',')[0] as col1, split(data,',')[1] as col2, ...`

Comment: I use the explode function.

Comment: In fact, every row has different amount of values and I just want to explode and append them with the same order.